Can't build and deploy a flutter web app to firebase hosting after updating firebase-tools
I have a flutter web app that runs locally on my machine when I give the command:
flutter run -d chrome

I was able to build and deploy using the following two commands:
flutter build web
firebase deploy --only hosting

I upgraded my flutter and firebase-tools and after, I can no longer successfully deploy my to firebase hosting.
My index.html is as follows:
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="qsportsgame">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>qsportsgame</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>

After I build and deploy, I am getting the following error on my production site:

Because I can run the code locally, I am inclined to think there is something wrong with the flutter_bootstrap.js. But I have no idea how to diagnose this problem because I can't replicate it on my local computer. Any help with how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

How can we reproduce your issue? Can we have repository?

Can confirm this started happening yesterday. Locally everything works fine (chrome and edge), uploading the exact same PWA to Github pages also works fine. Only deploying to Firebase Hosting gives issues. On X I posted some additional information and screenshots: https://x.com/plotsklapps/status/1805229841848930720
Thought it might be a cache problem, but even creating an entirely new flutterfire project did not solve the issue. Cannot figure out what's wrong, everything seems to point to the correct paths and I see no typo's.

Figured I'd rather downgrade for now:

npm uninstall -g firebase-tools

Then...

npm install -g firebase-tools@13.11.0

Or any other version than the latest from
https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools?activeTab=versions
Then...

flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter build web && firebase deploy

And you're back online.
Sorry for the ugly layout of this answer, but I'm on mobile right now. Good luck!

This worked to get my project back up and running on the website. I was having a heck of a time figuring out how to proceed. Ty very much
